# Angular 2 - ngfor - fields with spaces

Tags: javascript, html, angular2-template

I am just working on a sample application. I have a "Clients" service hooked up just fine to a "Clients" component. I can tell that I am getting an HTTP request that returns something similar to:

```
[{
   "ID": 1,
   "Client Name": "Test1"
 },
 {
   "ID": 2,
   "Client Name": "Test2"
 }
]
```

So in my `clients.componenet.html` file I am trying to just simply list the return

I am able to get the "ID" property just fine as such

`<li *ngFor="let client of clients">{{ client.ID }}</li>`

but I am trying to get that "Client Name" field.

I have tried a couple of things such as

`<li *ngFor="let client of clients">{{ client.ID }}: {{client[Client Name]}}</li>`

but none of that seems to work. What is the best way for me to access that property that has a space in the field name?

Comment: I'd try wrapping `Client Name` in quotes. Separately, I'd strongly consider doing a little for-loop upon receiving that data to change the key from `Client Name` to `ClientName` to "sanitize" the data and make it more maintainable in your view logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using client["Client Name"] instead of client[Client Name], that should work.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I can see that adding the quotes within the brackets would help and this certainly works.